# How to add an email address to Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

I've registered for Google Plus with my Gmail address. How can I associate another email address with my account, so that people who have that address can find me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to [Manage Account Information](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/EditUserInfo) and add an additional address.